# I used ui automator with android Junit4, but I got a nullPointerException

Tags: android, junit, android-uiautomator

When I init UiDevice I got a `NullPointerExecption` , here is my error information:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.UiAutomation.setOnAccessibilityEventListener(android.app.UiAutomation$OnAccessibilityEventListener)' on a null object reference
>   here is my code

**Code:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DailyTest  { 

    @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, false, true);
    @Before
     public  void  setUp(){
            Instrumentation instrumentation =InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
            Log.d(TAG,"instrumentation="+instrumentation);
            UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation);
            Log.d(TAG,"uiDevice="+uiDevice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ManoharReddy no this is not a duplicate question. What you have shared here is a generic null pointer exception and tianyu is getting this error specifically in Android instrumented tests. I suspect the wrong annotation is causing that issue.

Comment: @Sushant Somani ,it is Test and Before made this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `UiDevice` object only in the test method.
 Currently you have annotated method with `@Before` which can't initialize `UiDevice`.

Its better to change the annotation to `@Test` or initialize `UiDevice` in method annotated with `@Test`

If this doesn't help, please share you `Module` level `build.gradle`.

Comment: hello,i initialize UiDevice object in @Test ,but it still error,

Comment: this is my build.gradle:dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'


}

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xiangtianyu.dailytest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: i solve this problem ,i  should use adb command:adb shell am instrument -w -r -e class xxx ,but i use adb shell am instrument -e class xxx ,

Answer (score 0):

try running the tests on adb with -w flag. This may help.

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.example.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```